# Apache Cassandra Reading explanation

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

I am currently managing a percona xtradb cluster composed by 5 nodes, that hadle milions of insert every day. Write performance are very good but reading is not so fast, specially when i request a big dataset.

The record inserted are sensors time series.

I would like to try apache cassandra to replace percona cluster, but i don't understand how data reading works. I am looking for something able to split query around all the nodes and read in parallel from more than one node.

I know that cassandra sharding can have shard replicas. 
If i have 5 nodes and i set a replica factor of 5, does reading will be 5x faster?

Comment: ok i have understood that cassandra does not divede the work between nodes, but:

Comment: if i create small partitions of data with a primary key (sensor_id, date) and different partitions are stored in different nodes, when i ask data with a range of more than one day, are reads made in parallel reading data concurrently from different nodes?

Answer (score 0):

**Cassandra read path**

The read request initiated by a client is sent over to a coordinator node which checks the partitioner what are the replicas responsible for the data and if the consistency level is met.

The coordinator will check is it is responsible for the data. If yes, will satisfy the request. If no, it will send the request to fastest answering replica (this is determined using the [dynamic snitch](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dynamic-snitching-in-cassandra-past-present-and-future)). Also, a request digest is sent over to the other replicas.

The node will compare the returning data digests and if all are the same and the consistency level has been met, the data is returned from the fastest answering replica. If the digests are not the same, the coordinator will issue some read repair operations.

On the node there are a few steps performed: check row cache, check memtables, check sstables. More information: [How is data read?](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutReads.html) and [ReadPathForUsers](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ReadPathForUsers).

**Load balancing queries**

Since you have a replication factor that is equal to the number of nodes, this means that each node will hold all of your data. So, when a coordinator node will receive a read query it will satisfy it from itself. In particular(if you would use a LOCAL_ONE consistency level, the request will be pretty fast).

The client drivers implement the [load balancing policies](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/load_balancing/), which means that on your client you can configure how the queries will be spread around the cluster. Some more reading - [ClientRequestsRead](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlClientRequestsRead.html)

Answer (score 0):

> If i have 5 nodes and i set a replica factor of 5, does reading will be 5x faster?

No. It means you will have up to 5 copies of the data to ensure that your query can be satisfied when nodes are down. Cassandra does not divide up the work for the read. Instead it tries to force you to design your data in a way that makes the reads efficient and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to read cassandra is by making sure that each query you generate hits cassandra partition. Which means the first part of your simple primary(x,y,z) key and first bracket of compound ((x,y),z) primary key are provided as query parameters.
This goes back to cassandra table design principle of having a table design by your query needs.

Replication is about copies of data and Partitioning is about distributing data. 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archPartitionerAbout.html

some references about cassandra modelling,
https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/the-most-important-thing-to-know-in-cassandra-data-modeling-the-primary-key

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling

it is recommended to have 100 MB partitions but not compulsory.

You can use cassandra-stress utility to have look report of how your reads and writes look.